# What is sum of occurrences of zeros, at the end of integers, up to number $n$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What is sum of occurrences  of zeros, at the end of integers, up to number $n$ ? Let's call this function $O(n)$
Examples :
$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,$so $O(10)=1$
$1,...,20,$ so $O(20)=2$
$O(100)=11$
$O(200)=22$
$O(300)=33$
$O(300)=33$
$O(1000)=111$

Comment: Would $O(0)=1$ as it ends in a zero?  This could make for an unusual sequence or is this function defined only for Natural numbers?

Comment: @JB King good point, sometimes strange things happen aroud the zero :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a number $n$, the number within the range (1,n) with the most occurrence of trailing zeros is  `=number_of_digits_in_n - 1=`$\log(n)$
So we need to find the occurrence of multiple of $10_s$ upto $10^{\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor}$. Each occurrence is $\lfloor \frac{n}{10^i}\rfloor \forall i\le\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor$
So we just have to sum all such occrances

$$O(n)=\sum^{\lfloor \log(n)\rfloor}_{i=1} \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{ 10^i}\right\rfloor $$

Answer (score 6):

If you want the number of zeros less than a number $n$, note that a zero gets added if we hit a multiple of $10$, $2$ zeros get added if we hit a multiple of $100$ and in general $k$ zeros get added if we hit a multiple of $10^k$. Hence, the number of zeros is
$$\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{10}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{10^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{10^3}\right\rfloor + \cdots$$

Comment: yes, but what about closed form solution ? it seems to have something to do with `n(n+1)` sum ?

Comment: @Qbik Just as in the $p$-adic valuation of $n!$, it's $(n - \delta(n))/9$, where $\delta(n)$ is the "sum of digits" function.  It has nothing to do with $n(n+1)$ that I can tell.

Comment: @Erick Wong good point